# Finding overlapping employees in departments using excel

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula

I have my reference data which looks like this.

[image: Employee Data]

I'm trying to create a calendar using weekdays and 5 time slots as shown below.

[image: Calendar]

Using the calendar, I want to identify if there are any potential clashes between departments.

What I mean by that is:

1. On any particular day, an employee must only come in once if they work in the department (regardless of the time slot)
2. If there are two two departments working in a particular day, then an error message such as "Tax clashes with Legal" is returned.

As you can see from the reference data, employees work in multiple fields and I'm trying to minimise the amount of overlaps/clashes between the departments.

Desired results would look something like this:

[image: Desired Results]

Any help/guidance is appreciated!

Comment: I have hard time understanding the connections between reference data and calendar which of column in dereference data is Monday in calendar?

Comment: The reference data basically lists out the employee ID and the different job titles they have. I want to create a calendar (Mon-Fri) with 5 time slots where I can assign different job titles in different timeslots to come (say Tax and Legal). What I'm trying to figure out is how to program this calendar so that if I bring in Tax and Legal on the same day in different time slots it would return an error message saying Legal is clashing with Tax.

Comment: The reason why they clash is because I have an employee that works in both Tax and Legal and I can't have an employee working on the same day in two different jobs.

It should be able to identify different employee and where they overlap.

Comment: Still, why there is in results on Monday `Policy` if in job 1 column in reference data it isn't.

Comment: So if we look at the employee that work in Policy, we can see there are 2. These two employee can come on Monday. Where as on Monday, I can't bring in Tax and Legal as there is an employee that works in both departments  (see 1st employee). 

Hence why we have legal clashing with tax. There is an overlap occuring. There are no overlapping employee with Policy and tax or Policy and legal.

Comment: reference data is to be read in rows, eg first employee works in tax, legal and cyber. Employee number 3 works in IT and legal. So it makes sense that employee 1 and 3 overlap in the legal department. There would be a clash if i try to bring them in on the same day (regardless of timeslots)

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to print 'Employee ID' has clash with 'Employee ID'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252015/discussion-between-gren-man-and-alan-jones).

Comment: Hi, I have a question. Is there a limit to number of Jobs? Like, is it possible to exist a Job 6 or Job 7 and so on?

Comment: @Lucas, you can assume a maximum of 10 job titles.

Comment: Ok, and is there a limit  of works in a day?

Comment: The question is unclear. Please, edit your original question and add the info you posted on comments. Explain with a clear example how you calculate stuff. You talk about dates but you don't use dates and also you talked about employees with `Policy` but then switched to `Legal` and `Taxes`. How is each subject related? What is the data you are trying to show? How would you manually do it? Any other data available? Help yourself helping the community making your question clear and understandable.

Comment: @ Lucas, the limit is 5. I have 5 time slots per day.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns. The reference data shows all my employees and the different job titles they have. So for example, the first person works in tax, legal and cyber. I want to create a calendar where certain job title (dept) come in. Say I pick on monday tax and legal. I can see i have employee who have tax and legal as their job titles. So if they come in on monday, that means they will be doing 2 jobs which I'm trying to avoid. So in short, i'm trying to make sure no employee does 2 jobs on any particular day.

Comment: Why are you asking for collision detection instead of collision avoidance? Wouldn't you rather build flawless calendars in the first place? Also without knowing which employee is actually fulfilling each role, a collision detector does not have enough info to detect a collision. You need the calendar to support both the role/job and the employeeID. My 2cents: use a database with tables with unique indexes to guarantee you cannot duplicate what your business rules say must not be duplicated- in your case you cannot duplicate employee ID within the same day.

Comment: @spoiter  I can only work with the database i currently have. The best i can do with my current data is avoid a collision (clashes). So far I really like 'andrewb' solution to this problem. I'm open to seeing other solutions you may have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I think I understand what OP wants and here is my probably entirely unnecessarily complicated VBA solution:

### First, setup:

**Sheet "calendar", range A1:E6 looks like this:**

| Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tax | Media | Cyber |  |  |
| Legal | Cyber | Policy |  |  |
| Policy |  | IT |  |  |
|  |  | Legal |  |  |

**Sheet "empl", range A1:F10 looks like this:**

| ployee ID | Job 1 | Job 2 | Job 3 | Job 4 | Job 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 65465489 | Tax | Legal | Cyber |  |  |
| 46456464 | IT | Policy |  |  |  |
| 56489789 | IT | Legal |  |  |  |
| 64849489 | IT | International |  |  |  |
| 55544664 | Tax | Media |  |  |  |
| 19498794 |  | IT | Legal |  |  |
| 21649849 | Media | Legal | International |  |  |
| 48855564 |  | Tax |  | Tax |  |
| 654658246 |  | Cyber | Policy |  |  |

**Code in a "normal" VBA module:**

```vb
Const calendarSheet As String = "calendar"
Const calendarRange As String = "A2:E6"
Const employeeSheet As String = "empl"
Const employeeRange As String = "A2:F10"

Sub clashOfJobs()
    Dim employeeArr() As Variant, rng As Range, calendar As Variant
    
    Set rng = Worksheets(employeeSheet).Range(employeeRange)
    
    employeeArr = rng
    
    Set rng = Worksheets(calendarSheet).Range(calendarRange)
    
    calendar = rng
    
    Dim employees As Collection
    Set employees = employeeCol(employeeArr)
    
    Dim departments As Collection, dept As String
    
    For j = 1 To UBound(calendar, 2)
        Set departments = New Collection
        For i = 1 To UBound(calendar)
            dept = calendar(i, j)
            If dept <> "" Then
                departments.Add dept
                calendar(i, j) = clashes(employees, departments)
                'Debug.Print clashes(employees, departments)
            End If
        Next i
        
    Next j
    rng = calendar
End Sub

Function employeeCol(ByVal arr As Variant) As Collection
    Set employeeCol = New Collection
    Dim empl As Employee
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        Set empl = New Employee
        empl.id = arr(i, 1)
        If empl.id <> 0 Then
            For j = 2 To UBound(arr, 2)
                empl.addJob arr(i, j)
            Next j
            employeeCol.Add empl
        End If

    Next i
End Function

Function uniqueDepts(ByVal arr As Variant) As Collection
    Set uniqueDepts = New Collection
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        For j = 2 To UBound(arr, 2)
            On Error Resume Next
                If arr(i, j) <> "" Then uniqueDepts.Add arr(i, j), arr(i, j)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next j
    Next i
End Function

Function clashes(ByVal employees As Collection, depts As Collection) As String
    Dim separator As String
    separator = ", "
    
    Dim emp As Employee, dept As String, job As String, lastDept As String
    
    lastDept = depts(depts.Count)
    
    If depts.Count = 1 Then
        clashes = lastDept
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim clashCounter As Integer
    
    For i = 1 To depts.Count - 1
        dept = depts(i)
        clashCounter = 0
        For Each emp In employees
            If emp.hasJob(dept) And emp.hasJob(lastDept) Then
                If clashCounter = 0 Then
                    clashes = clashes & dept
                End If
                clashCounter = clashCounter + 1
            End If
        Next emp
        If clashCounter > 0 Then
            clashes = clashes & "(" & clashCounter & ")" & separator
        End If
    Next i
    If clashes <> vbNullString Then
        clashes = lastDept & " clashes with " & clashes
        clashes = Left(clashes, Len(clashes) - Len(separator))
        Else
            clashes = lastDept
        End If
End Function

Sub showOptions()
    Dim employeeArr() As Variant, rng As Range, calendar As Variant
    
    Set rng = Worksheets(employeeSheet).Range(employeeRange)
    
    employeeArr = rng
    
    Set rng = Worksheets(calendarSheet).Range(calendarRange)
    
    If Application.Intersect(Selection, rng) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Please select a calendar cell"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    calendar = rng
    
    Dim employees As Collection, uniqueDepartments As Collection
    Set employees = employeeCol(employeeArr)
    Set uniqueDepartments = uniqueDepts(employeeArr)
    
    Dim calRow As Integer, calCol As Integer
    calRow = Selection.Row - rng.Row + 1
    calCol = Selection.Column - rng.Column + 1
    
    Dim departments As Collection, cdpt As String
    Set departments = New Collection
    For i = 1 To calRow - 1
        cdpt = calendar(i, calCol)
        If cdpt = "" Then
            MsgBox "There are empty cells above your selection, select different cell"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        departments.Add cdpt, cdpt
    Next i
    
    Dim clashesStr As String
    For Each dept In uniqueDepartments
        On Error GoTo skip
            departments.Add dept, dept
            clashesStr = clashesStr & clashes(employees, departments) & vbCrLf
            departments.Remove departments.Count
skip:
            On Error GoTo -1
    Next dept
    
    MsgBox clashesStr
    
End Sub
```

**And finally, this has to be put in a CLASS module named "Employee":**

```vb
Private f_jobs As Collection
Private f_id As Long


Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set f_jobs = New Collection
End Sub

Public Sub addJob(ByVal job As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    If job <> "" Then jobs.Add job, job
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Property Get jobs() As Collection
    Set jobs = f_jobs
End Property

Property Get id() As Long
    id = f_id
End Property

Property Let id(ByVal id As Long)
    f_id = id
End Property

Public Function hasJob(ByVal job As String) As Boolean
    hasJob = False
    For Each j In f_jobs
        If j = job Then
            hasJob = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
End Function
```

**This is what the "Calendar" range looks like after running the "clashOfJobs" sub:**

| Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tax | Media | Cyber |  |  |
| Legal clashes with Tax | Cyber | Policy clashes with Cyber |  |  |
| Policy |  | IT clashes with Policy |  |  |
|  |  | Legal clashes with Cyber, IT |  |  |

*to have the code run automatically every time you change the calendar, you can add the following code into the SHEET module of the worksheet where your calendar is. You will have to modify the range again, same as with the code above.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Application.Intersect(Worksheets("calendar").Range("A2:E6"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        clashOfJobs
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I also added another sub "showOptions", how to use:
select a cell in the calendar that you want to fill and run the macro. A messagebox will pop up, showing you all the possible departments for that slot and what departments that are already in the calendar they clash with.

Comment: Hi @andrewb, thanks for your input. The code was really good. Just a few things. 
1) is it possible to add how many employees it has clashed with eg (Legal clashes with tax (3)) 
2) I'm not great with VBA, but is it possible to make it run continuously without me having to run it manually every time?

Comment: @AlanJones I modified the code so that it also counts the clashes (only the "clashes" function changed). As for the code running automatically, you can do that but when I attempted it with this code, it was throwing some errors and I'm not sure why to be honest. You can look up worksheet_change and try to figure it out. Anyway, optimal way to do this would be to have dropdown list in with non-clashing departments and have those lists update as you fill in the calendar. That would be extra work though. I might attempt it next week but no promises.

Comment: @AlanJones never mind my previous comment, I figured out why it was throwing errors. I added some code to the bottom of the answer. Anyway, there are better ways of doing this than blindly putting departments into the calendar and seeing if they clash. I'll look into it next week maybe.

Comment: @AlanJones I modified the code in the "normal" module again, there is an extra sub and I moved the calendar and employee range declarations to the top of the module and changed them to constants. The note regarding usage of new code is at the bottom of the answer. Please note that I have no idea if any of this works properly, please test it thoroughly before putting it in practice.

Comment: Hi @andrewb, it works perfectly fine. I tested it multiple times. Thank you for your time and patience :)

Comment: I really like @spoiter approach of collision avoidance to find optimal timeslots rather than collision detection. I guess this is something i need to think about further.

Comment: @AlanJones the new sub I added (see note at the bottom of the answer) should help with that. It basically loops through all available departments and shows collisions. It's not perfect but I think it should help.